# WordPress authentication cookie disclose usename

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have noticed that wordpress cookie includes the full username.
Is it possible to change its functionality hiding the username ?

I have tried using the solution as described here but had no luck

```
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/177473/removing-username-from-the-wordpress-logged-in-cookie
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What error did you get when you tried the solution mentioned in question?

Comment: It just didnt work.. it was a long time ago :-)

Comment: Okay :) Please post if you get any other solution.